# 'In Container.php line 752' class translator does not exist error in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Try to run existing laravel project from github. In **.env** file APIKEY is empty so i run

```
**php artisan key:generate**
```

command throw "In container.php line 752: class translator does not exist"